# Compare two XML files and save differences to a results file

Tags: c#, xml

I have two XML files that I need to compare for differences, the XML is very simple:

File 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Feeds zone="my zone">
  <Feed name="attribDump.json">ac1f07edc491a3d237cdfb1a17fc4551</Feed>
  <Feed name="focus_GroupsKV.txt">0f9e0a14a4ffce6ff5065b6e088c1f84</Feed>
  <Feed name="NAM_FORMATTED.csv">9e875496cdb072b5e54318d51295fdba</Feed>
  <Feed name="BNP\activityTitles.txt">2d27c0f19b71b4b411bcb00011d3f8b0</Feed>
</Feeds>
```

and File 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FeedsRequest version="1">
<Feeds zone="my zone">
  <Feed name="attribDump.json">ac1f07edc491a3d237cdfb1a17fc4551</Feed>
  <Feed name="focus_GroupsKV.txt">0f9e0a14a4ffce6ff5065b6e088c1f84</Feed>
  <Feed name="BNP\activityTitles.txt">e54c5b851ee3ff3f43b10d24f2316431</Feed>
</Feeds>
</FeedsRequest>
```

File 1 is an inventory list of files on our file share and File 2 is used by a disconnected device that will need to be refreshed from File 1.  The checks I need to make are 1) make sure all of the feeds in File 1 are in File 2 and 2) make sure any feeds that are found have the same hashCode(the long character string).  Once the checks have been completed, I need to create a response file that has a list of all of the feeds and then an attribute on each one that designates ok (file was found and matched), missing (file wasn't found), or updated (file was found but it was an older version).

So basically the result file would look as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FeedsResponse version="1">
<Feeds zone="my zone">
  <Feed name="attribDump.json" status="ok">ac1f07edc491a3d237cdfb1a17fc4551</Feed>
  <Feed name="focus_GroupsKV.txt" status="ok">0f9e0a14a4ffce6ff5065b6e088c1f84</Feed>
  <Feed name="NAM_FORMATTED.csv" status="missing">afd2c620053ed4f85ab02b4cc5f7a2b2</Feed>
  <Feed name="BNP\activityTitles.txt" status="updated">90805b851ee3ff3f43b10d24f2316431</Feed>
```

What I'm doing currently is looping through all of the files in File 1, then checking them against File 2 for differences.  Where I'm stuck, been a while since I've worked with XML, is how to build out the response document.

```
            FileInfo feedList = new FileInfo(_feedList);
        FileInfo feedRequest = new FileInfo(_feedRequest);

        // Load the documents
        XmlDocument feedListXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        feedListXmlDoc.Load(_feedList);

        // Load the documents
        XmlDocument feedRequestXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        feedRequestXmlDoc.Load(_feedRequest);

        //create response doc
        XmlDocument feedResponseXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

        // Define a single node
        XmlNode feedListNode;
        XmlNode feedRequestNode;

        // Get the root Xml element
        XmlElement feedListRoot = feedListXmlDoc.DocumentElement;
        XmlElement feedRequestRoot = feedRequestXmlDoc.DocumentElement;

        // Get a list of all player names
        XmlNodeList feedListXml = feedListRoot.GetElementsByTagName("Feed");
        XmlNodeList feedRequestXml = feedRequestRoot.GetElementsByTagName("Feed");

        // Create an XmlWriterSettings object with the correct options. 
        XmlWriter writer = null;
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        settings.IndentChars = ("  ");
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = false;

        // Create the XmlWriter object and write some content.
        writer = XmlWriter.Create(_resultPath, settings);
        writer.WriteStartElement("FeedsDiff");

        // The compare algorithm
        bool feedMatch = false;

        int j = 0;

        try 
        {
            // loop through list of current feeds
            for (int i = 0; i < feedListXml.Count; i++)
            {
                feedListNode = feedListXml.Item(i);

                string feedListName = feedListNode.Attributes["name"].Value.ToString();
                string feedListHash = feedListXml.Item(i).InnerText.ToString();

                //check feed request list for a match
                while (j < feedRequestXml.Count && feedMatch == false)
                {
                    feedRequestNode = feedRequestXml.Item(j);
                    string feedRequestName = feedRequestNode.Attributes["name"].Value.ToString();

                    //checks to see if feed names match
                    if (feedListName == feedRequestName)
                    {
                        feedMatch = true;
                        string feedRequestHash = feedRequestXml.Item(j).InnerText.ToString();

                        //since we found the node, we can remove it from the request list
                        XmlNode node = feedRequestNode.ParentNode;
                        node.RemoveChild(feedRequestNode);

                        //checks to see if hash codes match
                        if (feedListHash == feedRequestHash)
                        {
                            //if name and code match, move to the next one
                            feedMatch = true;

                            //add 'status="ok"' attribute to the node
                            //feedResponseXmlDoc.ImportNode(feedRequestNode,false);

                            Debug.WriteLine(feedListName + " name and hash match");

                            j = 0;
                        }
                        else 
                        {

                            feedMatch = true;

                            //feed has been updated since last device sync
                            //need to add status='update' attribute and append file to response
                            Debug.WriteLine(feedListName + " name matched but hash did not");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //names didn't match
                        //add status="missing" to the node
                        j++;
                    }
                }
                feedMatch = false;
            }
            // end Xml document
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.Flush();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (writer != null)
                writer.Close();
        }
```

Right now I'm trying to instantiate the response doc before the loop and then just add the elements as they are found but I'm having a hard time finding a concise way to do it.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you show your code that of which is relevant to the question you have posted..?

Comment: Added as requested.  I know it's a bit thin inside the loop, that's where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
public void CompareXml(string _feedList, string _feedRequest, string _resultPath)
    {
        FileInfo feedList = new FileInfo(_feedList);
        FileInfo feedRequest = new FileInfo(_feedRequest);

        // Load the documents
        XmlDocument feedListXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        feedListXmlDoc.Load(_feedList);

        // Load the documents
        XmlDocument feedRequestXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        feedRequestXmlDoc.Load(_feedRequest);

        // Define a single node
        XmlNode feedListNode;
        XmlNode feedRequestNode;

        // Get the root Xml element
        XmlElement feedListRoot = feedListXmlDoc.DocumentElement;
        XmlElement feedRequestRoot = feedRequestXmlDoc.DocumentElement;

        // Get a list of feeds for the stored list and the request
        XmlNodeList feedListXml = feedListRoot.GetElementsByTagName("Feed");
        XmlNodeList feedRequestXml = feedRequestRoot.GetElementsByTagName("Feed");

        bool feedLocated = false;
        int j = 0;

        try 
        {
            // loop through list of current feeds
            for (int i = 0; i < feedListXml.Count; i++)
            {
                feedListNode = feedListXml.Item(i);
                //create status attribute
                XmlAttribute attr = feedListXmlDoc.CreateAttribute("status");

                string feedListName = feedListNode.Attributes["name"].Value.ToString();
                string feedListHash = feedListXml.Item(i).InnerText.ToString();

                //check feed request list for a match
                while (j < feedRequestXml.Count && feedLocated == false)
                {
                    feedRequestNode = feedRequestXml.Item(j);
                    string feedRequestName = feedRequestNode.Attributes["name"].Value.ToString();

                    //checks to see if feed names match
                    if (feedRequestName == feedListName)
                    {
                        string feedRequestHash = feedRequestXml.Item(j).InnerText.ToString();

                        //checks to see if hashCodes match
                        if (feedListHash == feedRequestHash)
                        {
                            //if name and code match, set status to ok
                            attr.Value = "ok";

                            Debug.WriteLine(feedListName + " name and hash match. Status: 'ok'");
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            //if hashCodes don't match, set status attribute to updated
                            attr.Value = "updated";

                            Debug.WriteLine(feedListName + " name matched but hash did not. Status: 'updated'");
                        }
                        feedListNode.Attributes.Append(attr);
                        feedLocated = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //names didn't match, checking to see if we're at the end of  the request list
                        if (j + 1 == feedRequestXml.Count)
                        {
                            //file name wasn't found in the request list, set status attribute to missing
                            attr.Value = "missing";
                            feedListNode.Attributes.Append(attr);
                            feedLocated = true;
                            j = 0;

                            Debug.WriteLine("Reached the end of the file request list without a match. Status: 'missing'");
                        }
                        //file name wasn't located on this pass, move to next record
                        j++;
                    }
                }
                feedLocated = false;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Result file has been written out at " + _resultPath);
        }

        feedListXmlDoc.Save(_resultPath);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [differ](https://codeblocks.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Differ%20Sample&referringTitle=Home), from my open-source project [CodeBlocks](https://codeblocks.codeplex.com/) over on CodePlex, it was designed for situations such as this one. It is also available on Nuget as "[differ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/differ/)"